# Last value of python array repeating

Tags: python, arrays

I made a small script to sort out an array of random numbers in a ascending order.
Everything gets sorted correctly but the last value(The biggest value) gets repeated and throws an error "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list".

Basically how the script works is, using a for loop, get the smallest value, remove it and add it to a new array. Keep doing that and everything gets sorted.
I am attaching my code, any help is greatly appreciated. I am sorry of the intendation is off, formatting messed it up.

```
from random import randint
from random import sample
import random

global randomnum

def generateArray(size,lowerBound,upperBound):
    array = []
    array = random.sample(range(lowerBound,upperBound),size)
    return array

def sortArray(size,lowerBound,upperBound):
    useArray = generateArray(size,lowerBound,upperBound)
    print useArray
    arraysize = len(useArray)
    counter = 1
    minval = 0
    difsize = arraysize -1
    actualVal =0
    newArray =[]

    for i in range(0,arraysize+difsize):
        for n in range(0,arraysize-1):
            if useArray[minval] < useArray[counter]:
                counter = counter +1
                actualVal = useArray[minval]
            else:
                minval = counter
                actualVal = useArray[counter]
                counter = counter +1
        arraysize = arraysize -1
        counter =1
        minval =0
        # Adding this code fixed it
        if i + arraysize ==i:
            newArray.extend(useArray)   
            return newArray


        print actualVal
        #t = len(newArray)
        #print t
        newArray.append(actualVal)
        useArray.remove(actualVal)

   return newArray






print sortArray(10,1,30)
```

Comment: Hint: [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys, i managed to find a work around and change the code a bit to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your actual problems is that you are stepping over more than the array size with an index of `arraysize+difsize` you also have a small chance that there is more than one value with a given result, especially if the size is big and the range small and `remove` will remove all of the occurences.

Why not use pythons built in facilities.
Try:

```
import random

def generateArray(size,lowerBound,upperBound):
    """ Generate a random array as required """
    array = random.sample(range(lowerBound,upperBound),size)
    return array

def sortArray(size,lowerBound,upperBound):
    """ Generate a sorted random array """
    useArray = generateArray(size,lowerBound,upperBound)
    print useArray
    useArray.sort()
    print useArray
    return useArray
```

If you have to do it manually try a bubble sort:

```
def sortArray(size,lowerBound,upperBound):
    """ Generate a sorted random array """
    useArray = generateArray(size,lowerBound,upperBound)
    print useArray
    changed = True:
    while changed:
         changed = False
         for n in xrange(size-1):
             if useArray[n] > useArry[n+1]:
                 useArray[n], useArry[n+1] = useArray[n+1], useArry[n]
                 changed = True
    return useArray
```

Bubble sort is not the fastest sort but it is one of the simplest and will normally finish faster than your current technique which will be quite slow.

Comment: I could go for that, but i am suppose to do the whole sorting manually.